# Javascript: How to delete parent list item of embedded delete button

Tags: javascript, css

Building a beginners to-do list in vanilla JS. My relevant code is as follows;

```
let newList = document.querySelector("ul");
//let newList = document.createElement("ul");
let unordered = document.getElementById("tasks")
  let deletebtn = document.querySelector(".btn")


addTask.addEventListener("click", function() {
    let input = document.getElementById("input-task").value;
    //push to array - used when deleting indiviual LI
    taskArr.push(input);
        //Create Text Node
        let newTextNode = document.createTextNode(input);
        let newListItem = document.createElement("li");
      
        const btn = document.createElement("button");
        btn.className = "btn";
        btn.innerHTML = "Delete"
        const completeBtn = document.createElement("button");
        completeBtn.className = "finished";
        completeBtn.innerHTML = "Finished";

        //Apend text node and list item
        newListItem.appendChild(newTextNode);
        unordered.appendChild(newListItem).className = "li";
        newListItem.appendChild(btn);
        newListItem.appendChild(completeBtn);

    btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
       e.parentNode.parentElement.removeChild(e);
    })

    completeBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        completeBtn.parentElement.classList.add("strike");
    })
})

removeAll.addEventListener("click", function() {
    newList.innerHTML = "";
    taskArr = [];    
});
```

I can't seem to figure out how to delete the list item associated with the delete button. The click listener is working but I am getting "parent element of undefined" as an error. Likewise, when I try and add my "strike" class on the completed button (which would turn the LI a different color and text strike though), the class is being applied to the "LI" but not changing the style.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `e` is an event object and not a DOM node, hence it cannot be a child of any element in the DOM. It therefor also has no `.parentElement` property. This fact should have been quite obvious because your browser will throw an error because of this -> check your console (which is also the first step for debugging)

Comment: `.removeChild()` can only remove direct children. Assuming that `e` would be an actual element (see first comment) you cannot remove `e` from its _grand parent_ (`.parentNode.parentElement` (why `parentNode` but then `parentElement`?)).

Comment: I used parent node because I assumed it would jump to the LI text node, and from there jump to the UL.

Comment: Ah I got it!     btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
       newListItem.parentNode.removeChild(newListItem)
       
    })

Answer (score 0):

```
btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
   newListItem.parentNode.removeChild(newListItem)
   
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
let btn = document.querySelector(".btn");

btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.target.closest("li").remove();
})
```

BTW instead of creating that much items and appending some attributes, you can type an HTML template and use it when you add a new list item. It's difficult to read your code. Let me give you a simple example:

```
let ul = document.querySelector("ul");
let liTemplate = (text, label) => {
 return `<li class="li-classes">
            <span class="li-text">${text}</span>
            <button class="btn-classes">${label}</button>
         </li>`
}
ul.insertAdjacentHTML= liTemplate("add some text", "delete");
```

Comment: Thank you! My code wasn't as poorly written until I started throwing things at the wall to see what stuck. I honestly could not figure it out so I started to change everything around and separate items so I could target them more easily.